# Error:- type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get away from this error or what else I can call instead of List dynamic or Future dynamic or how can I convert List into Future?I just want to display this text from firestore.[image]
Error:-

```
     Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<dynamic>'
```

Getting data this way and commented line which takes me to error:-

```
    class EditInfo extends StatefulWidget{
    @override
   EditInfoState createState () => EditInfoState();
   }


  class EditInfoState extends State<EditInfo>
 with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
 final CollectionReference _reference =   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
 final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 CreateAccountData accountData;

 Future myInterest;


    
    getalldata() async {
    Future<CreateAccountData> getUser() async {
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    return _reference.doc(user.uid).get().then((m) =>  CreateAccountData.fromDocument(m));
    }
    getUser().then((value)async{
    accountData= value;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usercollection.doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get();
   myInterest = doc.data()['hobbies'];///Error takes me to,myInterest

     });
 }
```

Displaying it in grid view:-

```
       child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: myInterest,
                      builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                        if(!snapshot.hasData){
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        } if(snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty){
                          return Align(
                            alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
                            child: Text("Add what you love to do.....",textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),),
                          );
                        }return GridView.builder(
                            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 5, crossAxisSpacing: 5,),
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                             // DocumentSnapshot interestList = snapshot.data.docs[index]['hobbies'];
                              return Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
                                child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['hobbies']),
                              );
                            }
                        );

                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: How you declared `myInterest` ?

Comment: Future myInterest;

Comment: Please provide your code snippet with `myInterest `

Comment: @GAGANSINGH `doc.data()['hobbies'];` will be returning a List.

Comment: where and what changes I need to make now? So, that I can get and display data. Is it in the future builder?

Comment: @GAGANSINGH Try to assign `myInterest = usercollection.doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get();` and check. In the current format I can't reproduce it at my end.

Comment: made no difference.

Comment: which line throws that error ?

Comment: I have commented that line in getalldata(),last line myInterest.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are assigning a List to a variable declared as Future.

You are declaring:

```
 Future myInterest;
```

and then setting a value that is not a future to it:

```
myInterest = doc.data()['hobbies'];
```

Ultimately there is a lot of way to resolve this, one of which:

```
Future getAllData() async {
  // do the api stuff
  return doc.data()['hobbies'];
};
```

Then assign to it:

```
myInterest = getAllData();
```

I encourage you to learn about futures though.

Comment: Future<Interest>:-The name 'Interest' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument

Comment: I also encourage you to learn about types, let me edit my code so it does not give you this error

Comment: Changed `Future<Interest>` return type to `Future`

Comment: where I have to assign myInterest? I think I have assigned somewhere wrong as it has not made any change.

Comment: It really depends on what you intend to do. By barely looking at your code I think what you want is to make that assignement in the onInit method - or constructor of the widget.

Comment: Nope sorry, I explained what the error was but I have work of my own to do. I hope it will help you. I assure you that this error is due to wrong types.